# Better MySQL Syntax for my query

Tags: mysql, pdo

HI I have the following query:

```
SELECT PAS_User.user_user_id, 
PAS_User.user_city, 
PAS_User.user_company, 
PAS_User.user_country, 
PAS_User.user_account_type, 
PAS_User.user_account_premium, 
PAS_User.user_sign_up_date, 
PAS_User.user_first_name, 
PAS_User.user_last_name, 
PAS_User.user_avatar_url, 
PAS_User.user_cover_image_url, 
PAS_User.user_bio, 
PAS_User.user_sector, 
PAS_User.user_job_type, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `PAS_Follow` WHERE `folw_follower_user_id`=:sid) AS user_following_count,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `PAS_Follow` WHERE `folw_followed_user_id`=:sid) AS user_followed_count,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `PAS_Post` WHERE `post_user_id`=:sid) AS user_post_count, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `PAS_Follow` WHERE `folw_follower_user_id`=:sid AND `folw_followed_user_id`=:cid) AS user_this_user_is_following, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `PAS_Follow` WHERE `folw_followed_user_id`=:cid AND `folw_follower_user_id`=:sid) AS user_this_user_is_followed 
FROM PAS_User 
WHERE `PAS_User`.`user_user_id`=:sid
```

Which is designed to get counts from other tables for a profile page and the basic user details where :sid = 1 and :cid = 2.

The question is, is there any better way of achieving this in perhaps a smaller query or in a cleaner way?

The tables used are

> PAS_User , PAS_Follow & PAS_Post

Thanks

Justin

Comment: Why do you repeat that PAS_User. thing so much?

Comment: One can never be too verbose. While it's technically not needed here it doesn't cost any performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [denormalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) all those counter fields and only update them when a user posts something, or presses a **Follow** button. Your current query is going to blow up your database server in the foreseeable future if your website gets actual active users.

Comment: I thought about that however the query is designed so that as a user arrives at a profile the information is live and realtime however I will look into Denormailsation

Comment: It's the only possible optimization, and if you read the linked page you should pay extra attention to the last line: **"Denormalization techniques are often used to improve the scalability of Web applications"**. That's what it's for - preventing server problems and speeding up queries, in situations where fast responses are of critical importance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be honest.  I don't really like nested `select` statements (`select` within `select`).  However, in your case, the alternative may be uglier and prone to performance errors.  The temptation is to do something like:

```
select . . .
from PAS_User u left outer join
     (select folw_foller_user_id, count(*) as user_following_count
      from PAS_Follow pf
      group by folw_foller_user_id
     ) pf
     on pf.folw_foller_user_id = u.user_user_id left outer join
     . . .
```

Fine.  But this will perform much worse than your original query, because of the outside filter on `user_user_id`.  To fix this, you would repeat the condition in the subquery:

```
select . . .
from PAS_User u left outer join
     (select folw_foller_user_id, count(*) as user_following_count
      from PAS_Follow pf
      where folw_foller_user_id = :sid
      group by folw_foller_user_id
     ) pf
     on pf.folw_foller_user_id = u.user_user_id left outer join
     . . .
```

Or even:

```
select . . .
from PAS_User u cross join
     (select count(*) as user_following_count
      from PAS_Follow pf
      where folw_foller_user_id = :sid
     ) pf
     on pf.folw_foller_user_id = u.user_user_id left outer join
     . . .
```

And I might even argue that repeating the condition in *one* subquery would be good.  I cannot make that argument for five subqueries.

To make this clear, the best syntax is to user window functions:

```
select . . .
       count(*) over (partition by folw_fllower_user_id) as user_following_count,
       . . .
```

Alas, MySQL does not support window functions.  A very reasonable replacement, in my opinion, are subqueries (which would normally be correlated).  This supports your initial syntax.